# A master-detail TabControl binding (1:n) using parent SelectedItem with ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have XAML related question I have tried to research an answer in vain. I have commented the relevant questions to the XAML. It looks to me this questions is a more complex because of the way I try to arrange things.

Basically I have a main view model used in the TabControl headers and then in the content area I would show a list of items from the main view model. I just don't know how to to the binding. This is the main question. However, I suspect the next and ultimate objectives I have might factor in how to think about this, so I added them too. The rest of the code is for the sake of completeness.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TabControl x:Name="mainsTabControl"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
             IsEnabled="True"
             Visibility="Visible"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Mains}">

        <!-- How to select a different background for the selected header? Note that the background color is "selected tab" if MainContentViewModel.IsActive is not TRUE.
             If it is, a different color is chosen. Here this fact is just emulated with IsEnabled property due to well, multi-binding to the rescue (and a converter)? -->

        <!-- Is there a clean way to use ICommand binding (RelayCommand) to check if it is OK to change the tab and if necessary, present a dialogue asking for the change? -->
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsActive}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

        <!-- This binds to every item in the MainViewModel.Mains collection. Note the question about background color. -->
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- This binding gives reference to the selected MainContentViewModel. -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=mainsTabControl, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomItems}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfDependencyInjection.ViewModel
{
public class MainContentViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<CustomItemViewModel> customItems;

    private mainContentDto MainContent { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; }


    public bool isActive;


    public MainContentViewModel(Engine engine, mainContentDto mainContent)
    {
        MainContent = mainContent;
        Name = MainContent.Name;
        IsActive = true;

        //The custom items belonging to this main content.
        var customItems = engine.CustomItemContents.Where(i => i.MainContentId == MainContent.Id).Select(i => new CustomItemViewModel(engine, i));
        CustomItems = new ObservableCollection<CustomItemViewModel>(customItems);
    }


    public ObservableCollection<CustomItemViewModel> CustomItems
    {
        get
        {
            return customItems;
        }
        set
        {
            customItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CustomItems));
        }
    }


    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            return isActive;
        }
        private set
        {
            isActive = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsActive));
        }
    }
}
}

public class CustomItemViewModel: ViewModelBase
{
    private Engine Engine { get; }

    private ItemTypeDto  CustomItem { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; }        


    public CustomItemViewModel(Engine engine, ItemTypeDto customItem)
    {
        Engine = engine;
        CustomItem = customItem;
        Name = customItem.Name;
    }
}

namespace WpfDependencyInjection
{    
public class Engine
{
    public string Name { get; } = "EngineMan";

    public List<mainContentDto> MainContents { get; set; } = new List<mainContentDto>(new[]
    {
        new mainContentDto { Name = "Main One", Id = Guid.Parse("C51AC758-504B-4914-92DC-5EBE9A1F39E1"), Version = 1 },
        new mainContentDto { Name = "Main Two", Id = Guid.Parse("C51AC758-504B-4914-92DC-5EBE9A1F39E2"), Version = 1 }
    });


    public List<ItemTypeDto> CustomItemContents { get; set; } = new List<ItemTypeDto>(new ItemTypeDto[]
    {            
        new ItemType1Dto { MainContentId = Guid.Parse("C51AC758-504B-4914-92DC-5EBE9A1F39E1"), Name = "ItemType1Dto I", Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Version = 1 },
        new ItemType2Dto { MainContentId = Guid.Parse("C51AC758-504B-4914-92DC-5EBE9A1F39E1"), Name = "ItemType2Dto I", Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Version = 1 },

        new ItemType2Dto { MainContentId = Guid.Parse("C51AC758-504B-4914-92DC-5EBE9A1F39E2"), Name = "ItemType2Dto 2", Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Version = 1 }
    });


    public Engine()
    {
    }
}
}
```

<edit: The binding solved partially, though not the ICommand part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TabControl x:Name="mainsTabControl"
            IsEnabled="True"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Mains}"
            SelectedItem="0"
            Visibility="Visible">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="HotPink" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainContentViewModel}">
            <Button Background="{x:Null}"
                    Command="{Binding SomeCommand}"
                    Content="{Binding Name}"
                    FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MainContentViewModel}">
            <ItemsControl Margin="10"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CustomItems}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CustomItem}">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**Command:**

There may be cleaner ways but here we bind `IsSelected` for the `TabItem` to the `IsSelected` property of the viewmodel. This enables having a command that asks if it is ok to navigate and sets `IsSelected` to true if it is.

**Background:**

We also retemplate the tabitem so that background works as we want. If you check with Snoop WPF inserts an extra border when the item is selected.

**Side note 1:**

Don't put the `TabControl` into a `StackPanel` like that. A `StackPanel` sizes to content and will kill scrolling and draw outside the control. Also it comes with a cost, a deep visual tree is not cheap. Same in the `ItemTemplate` and the other places. In fact `StackPanel` is rarely right for anything :)

**Side note 2:**

If you specify `DataType` in your `DataTemplate` you get intellisense and some compiletime checking.